# vb.net send mail is failing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

What am I missing in the code below? I am getting a failure sending email message.

```
Private Sub sendTestEmail()

 Dim EmailBody As String

 EmailBody = "This is a test *****************"


 Dim TestEmail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("webserver@companyname.com",   "Smilinglily@companyname.com", "TestEmail", EmailBody)

 Dim EmailServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost")
 EmailServer.SendAsync(TestEmail, Me)

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the message, exactly?  Error details matter.

Comment: I bet your box is not set up as an smptp server properly. If you are using Widnows, go to InetPub\mailroot; I'm sure you'll see all your emails there, waiting to be sent

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on localhost?

Comment: Are you sure that there is an email server running on your local machine and on the default smtp port?!?

Comment: it will be better if you use the code within try catch statement

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. When I changed the SmtpClient from localhost to "smtp.companyname.com" and used smtp.send(testmail) instead of smtp.sendasync(testmail,me) it started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code came from [here](http://vbnotebookfor.net/vbnb_netmail.htm)

It is probably that your SMTP server is not installed or configured on localhost.

It could also be a security problem stopping your localhost SMTP server from forwarding the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I Have written the class which can perform this task easyly.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class GGSMTP_GMAIL
    Dim Temp_GmailAccount As String
    Dim Temp_GmailPassword As String
    Dim Temp_SMTPSERVER As String
    Dim Temp_ServerPort As Int32
    Dim Temp_ErrorText As String = ""
    Dim Temp_EnableSSl As Boolean = True
    Public ReadOnly Property ErrorText() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_ErrorText
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property EnableSSL() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Temp_EnableSSl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Temp_EnableSSl = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property GmailAccount() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_GmailAccount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_GmailAccount = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property GmailPassword() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_GmailPassword
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_GmailPassword = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property SMTPSERVER() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_SMTPSERVER
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_SMTPSERVER = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ServerPort() As Int32
        Get
            Return Temp_ServerPort
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32)
            Temp_ServerPort = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal GmailAccount As String, ByVal GmailPassword As String, Optional ByVal SMTPSERVER As String = "smtp.gmail.com", Optional ByVal ServerPort As Int32 = 587, Optional ByVal EnableSSl As Boolean = True)
        Temp_GmailAccount = GmailAccount
        Temp_GmailPassword = GmailPassword
        Temp_SMTPSERVER = SMTPSERVER
        Temp_ServerPort = ServerPort
        Temp_EnableSSl = EnableSSl
    End Sub
    Public Function SendMail(ByVal ToAddressies As String(), ByVal Subject As String, ByVal BodyText As String, Optional ByVal AttachedFiles As String() = Nothing) As Boolean
        Temp_ErrorText = ""
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(Temp_SMTPSERVER)
        Mail.Subject = Subject
        Mail.From = New MailAddress(Temp_GmailAccount)
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Temp_GmailAccount, Temp_GmailPassword) '<-- Password Here
        Mail.To.Clear()
        For i As Int16 = 0 To ToAddressies.Length - 1
            Mail.To.Add(ToAddressies(i))
        Next i
        Mail.Body = BodyText
        Mail.Attachments.Clear()

        If AttachedFiles IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Int16 = 0 To AttachedFiles.Length - 1
                Mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachedFiles(i)))
            Next
        End If

        SMTP.EnableSsl = Temp_EnableSSl
        SMTP.Port = Temp_ServerPort

        Try
            SMTP.Send(Mail)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Temp_ErrorText = ex.Message.ToString
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

Its the way, how to use class:

```
Dim GGmail As New GGSMTP_GMAIL("MyFromAddress1@gmail.com", "AccPassword", )

        Dim ToAddressies As String() = {"ToAddress1@gmail.com", "ToAddress2@gmail.com"}
        Dim attachs() As String = {"d:\temp_Excell226.xlsx", "d:\temp_Excell224.xlsx", "d:\temp_Excell225.xlsx"}
        Dim subject As String = "My TestSubject"
        Dim body As String = "My text goes here ...."
        Dim result As Boolean = GGmail.SendMail(ToAddressies, subject, body, attachs)
        If result Then
            MsgBox("mails sended successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox(GGmail.ErrorText, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
```

Hope this helps. Good coding